# Multiple Google Maps on same page

Tags: google-maps

I have seen some topics about this on this forum but didn't get the answer I was looking for.

If I'm using such a code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        window.onload = function(){
            var pinkParksStyles = '';
        var pinkMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(pinkParksStyles,
            {name: "Our Location"});
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3850639,2.1734035),
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'pink_parks']
            }
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas1'), mapOptions);
          map.mapTypes.set('pink_parks', pinkMapType);
          map.setMapTypeId('pink_parks');


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3850639,2.1734035),
            map: map
        }); 
        }
    })();
   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        window.onload = function(){
            var pinkParksStyles = '';
        var pinkMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(pinkParksStyles,
            {name: "Our Location"});
        var mapOptions2 = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3850639,2.1734035),
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'pink_parks']
            }
        };
        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas2'), mapOptions2);
          map2.mapTypes.set('pink_parks', pinkMapType);
          map2.setMapTypeId('pink_parks');


        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3850639,2.1734035),
            map: map2
        }); 
        }
    })();
   </script>
```

So I have two divs with ID map_canvas1 and map_canvas2. But only the second one gets shown. I have this imported in the header of the document: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false

I need to make both work but with seperated javascript. Did manage it with getting all into same function, but I need it to be seperated.

Any advice?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

make two seperate javascript functions out of it, and put both in the onload function.

Like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  function1(variable);
  function2(variable);
}

function1(variable) {
  do stuff;
}

function2(variable)
  do other stuff;
}
```

Alternatively you could use jQuery to handle the onload, i think that can actually add multiple handlers to the body onload. See also http://api.jquery.com/ready/

javascriptmap.php?map=xxx

```
$(function() {
  $("#divID").each( function() {
    showMap(divID);
  });
});

showMap(divID) {
  show map on #divID
};
```

On the html/php file:

```
<script scr="javascriptmap.php?map=map1" />
<script scr="javascriptmap.php?map=map2" />
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks will give it a try. Any change of getting totally seperated? I'm try this with multiple maps that build it's javascript on fly. So when some maps appears I want to add javascript for it, since I won't know how many will still come.

Comment: Hi again. This is all ok. But I still need to get the load function separated. As said, I am building javascript on fly. So need to output for maps #1 and then after some code for map#2 and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: I think jQuery can do it totally seperated. It might be a bit much to use jQuery just for this, but generally when you start using it, it's hard to do things without it. I like to use jQuery as well for only starting the function when the corresponding div is there. Otherwise you could also generate the script file with php or similar and call that on demand. It's generally better to put that javascript in a seperate file anyway. If you got a jsFiddle or more code I could assist more if needed.

Comment: Hi again. Seems that just calling map1get() and map2get() without ready or load wrapper seem to do the trick.

Comment: Keep in mind for most maps it's important the DOM is actually loaded. When you start putting your javascript in seperate js files those load wrappers start to get important so keep that in mind. If you need any more help please say so and else mark this answer as accepted please :)

Comment: But why, now that I have seperated call for this 2 functions, if I add each one a load wrapper it doesn't work anymore? My example: http://jsfiddle.net/8BrDY/

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly here, but you cannot set an ordinary load wrapper twice because they overwrite each other then. Maybe https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async can help you further?